# How to set/see my email?

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

I am new to SP, using 2010, and have my account tied to active directory.  Yet in SP I cannot see my email address anywhere.  How can I know what address is using?

Ok, I CAN see my address under My Settings.  However, only when I am on My Site.  When I go to the default site that value is blank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that your user profile has changed, but SharePoint didn't pick up the changes. [Here's a post with some suggestions](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-7-SharePoint_2007__All_you_ever_wanted_to_know_about_User_Profiles.aspx).

Comment: Right, the account sync service was not running properly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another Quick fix for this, if you are not using the profile service it to simply delete the user from the site collection and add them back in. What has happened to me is I will create a test account with out populating the email field in AD and then add that account to SharePoint. Then realize that I forgot to add teh email go back to AD add the email and then it does not show up in SharePoint. The solution is delete the accout from SharePoint and add it back in and there will be the email.